# TCP-Program gets no connection from remote pc

Tags: qt, sockets, tcp

I have written two programs which talk to each other via (QT-)TcP. If both of them are running on my pc (e.g. using 127.0.0.1 as address), everything is going fine. As soon as I deploy one of both programs on another pc, I get no connection back, e.g. connecting from my program (on port 40000 and 40002) to the running TcP-servers on the other pc works, but not from the other pc on the ports 40001 and 40003. Is it because my ports are closed? I already tried to open them, but nmap can not tell me more about them. How can I find a solution?

Update: According to netstat the servers on the neccessary ports on the local and remote pc are listening (for example:

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:40002           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      off (0.00/0/0)
```

), but I only can connect from my computer to the remote one, not the other way round.

Another possibility of error: I am running my dev system in a VM with NAT-connection to the outside. Could that be the problem that I do not get an incoming signal?

Comment: Your firewall is probably blocking the ports. Maybe the listen address is wrong (127.0.0.1 ?). You can test with netstat -a -n -o which addresses are open (check whether the ports 40001 and 40003 are being listened on and the listen address is correct)

Comment: I've updated my answer with after NAT comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's likely to be a bind issue, and/or a firewall issue.

If your listener is only bound on 127.0.0.1 then connections between 2 machines won't work as the traffic isn't heard on the interface. You need to set the bind address to 0.0.0.0 (which means any) usually to achieve this.

Also, check your firewall isn't blocking your traffic on these ports if they are bound to any interface.

**EDIT** Example netstat looking for 7001 (WebLogic admin port) showing listening on various interfaces

```
$ netstat -nl | grep 7001
tcp6       0      0 192.168.1.149:7001      :::*                    LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:7001          :::*                    LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 ::1:7001                :::*                    LISTEN
```

**EDIT 2** I see you're on NAT. Traffic originating from target will not be routed back to your own VM. Try changing to bridged network that's on the same range as the target, if you're using DHCP to get IP addresses, then that'll be easiest way for your VM to register an IP that will work.

Comment: My server is listening to all ip addresses `(tcpServer->listen(QHostAddress::Any, Server::port)`, therefore I don't think that that is the problem. How can I check if ports are bound?

Comment: I get no report about occupied ports.

Comment: Then there's no process listening on that port I've added example from my own output from a typical listener

Comment: I added an update above, everything is open and should listen.